# SharePoint 2010 & Web Parts & PDF links does not open in Adobe client

Tags: pdf, sharepoint

Good Afternoon All,
 I have a report that lists a series of pdf document from a document library in SharePoint. When I click on a one of the documents from this web part, then IE will try to download the pdf document. What I want is....a pdf document to open in the adobe reader client from the web part, without using OpenPDF.js or any third party client library. This works when I click on a link of a pdf document directly from a document library. In this case the document opens adobe reader client.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,

Comment: IS this a custom web part or an OOTB web part?

Comment: No a custom web part.

Answer (score 0):

If your tag for the link looks like

```
 <a href="DocLink" title="Tooltip">
```

Try

```
<a href="DocLink" title="Tooltip" target="_blank">
```

Also check out what someone else had to do
http://mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1187

Cheers
Truez